# How to copy values from one row to another inside the same database?

Tags: mysql, sql, rows

I am managing a database that has two tables for "experience" values. I am trying to copy the values from the first experience table to the second one, but the query won't go through. This is what I've got until now.

**Tables:**
-**mob_db_re** //Target table
-**mob_db** //Source Table

**Query syntax:**

```
UPDATE mob_db_re  
INNER JOIN mob_db ON mob_db.EXP = mob_db_re.EXP  
SET mob_db_re.EXP = mob_db.EXP
```

Comment: Are you trying to INSERT a record into mob_db_re, or UPDATE an existing record in mob_db_re?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy all the rows from one table to another try using a `SELECT INTO` statement:

```
SELECT *
INTO mob_db_re
FROM mob_db;
```

This will work if the tables have the same schema, otherwise you will have to specify the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to copy one table to another

1. If they have same schema, use this one

   `INSERT INTO mob_db_re (SELECT * FROM mob_db)`
2. If they do not have same schema, use this one

   ```
   INSERT INTO mob_db_re (column1, column2, column3, ...)
   SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... FROM mob_db
   ```

Also you can add WHERE condition to the above SELECT statement if needed.

For some reason, If you to need to update instead of insert, use this one

```
UPDATE mob_db_re 
SET re.EXP= db.EXP
FROM mob_db_re re
INNER JOIN mob_db db
ON re.EXP= db.EXP;
```